# patch.fixWebscriptTemplate failed

Tags: upgrade, alfresco

During an upgrade from Alfresco community 4.2 to 5.1 the upgrade fails on patch patch.fixWebscriptTemplate.

2019-03-26 14:44:01,217 ERROR [org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter] [localhost-startStop-1] 
=== Failed to apply patch         === 
ID: patch.fixWebscriptTemplate

Does anybody know this patch and why it failes?

Answer (score 0):

Delete sample webscript in 
dictionary/webscripts/org/alfresco

the migration of the repository should go futher